# InvalidArgumentException in Carbon::createFromDate()->age

Tags: php, laravel, validation, date, php-carbon

Hello i'm writing a custom validation for input data in my laravel project. I'm using Carbon::createFromDate()->age in order to get user age and check whether he's 16 or more. I reckon i'm not doing it properly because i get
 **InvalidArgumentException**  with such errors:

The separation symbol could not be found

The separation symbol could not be found

A two digit minute could not be found

Unexpected data found.

Trailing data

$rok is a year(1996 eg.) $miesiac is a month and $dzien is a Day. Pesel is an unique ID number of a Polish citizen. From pesel i get the date(year, month, day)

I'm getting some big numbers and i don't know what they mean Here's dd: "year:21586738427 month:1900167 day:9001727"

Here's code of my AppServiceProvider

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Validator;
use Log;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //Custom validator for pesel validation
        Validator::extend('pesel',function($attribute,$value,$parameters)
        {
          $v = $value;
          //check if psesel is 11 chars long
          if (strlen($v) != 11)
          {
            Log::info("Pesel is not 11 chars long");
            return;
          }
          //check whether all chars are numbers

          $aInt = array();

          for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++)
          {
           $val = substr($v,$i+1);
           $valInt = (int) $val;
           $aInt[$i] = $valInt;
         if(is_nan($aInt[$i]))
            {
                Log::info("User inserted invalid number");
                return;
            }
          }


          //check control sum
          $wagi = [1,3,7,9,1,3,7,9,1,3,1];
          $sum = 0;
          for($i = 0;$i < 11;$i++)
          {
            $sum += $wagi[$i]*$aInt[$i];
            if(Log::info(($sum%10)!=0))
            {
              return;
            }
          //count the year,month,and day from pesel
          $rok = 1900+$aInt[0]*10+$aInt[1];
          if($aInt[2]>=2 && $aInt[2]<8)
          {
            $rok += floor($aInt[2]/2)*100;
          }
          if($aInt[2]>=8)
          {
            $rok -= 100;
          }
          $miesiac = ($aInt[2]%2)*10+$aInt[3];
          $dzien = $aInt[4]*10+$aInt[5];
          Log::info("Parsing the date in carbon");

          //validate whether user is 16 years or more
          $userAge =  Carbon::createFromDate($rok, $miesiac, $dzien,'Europe/Warsaw')->age;
          if($userAge < 16)
          {
            Log::info("user is not 16 or more");
            return;
          }



        }

      });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you specify the values of `$rok`, `$miesiac` & `$dizen`?

Comment: $rok is a year(1996 eg.)  $miesiac  is  a month  and $dzien  is a Day.  Pesel  is an unique  ID number  of a Polish  citizen. From  pesel  i get  the date(year, month, day)

Comment: Are you sure, can `dd()` all the 3 of them, and add that result to your question!

Comment: You're right, I'm getting some big numbers and i don't know what they mean
Here's dd: "year:21586738427 month:1900167 day:9001727"

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved the problem. It was fault of my code

```
  $val = substr($v,$i+1);
```

is wrong 
it should be

```
  $val = substr($v,$i,1);
```

Now it works