# Carbon return InvalidArgumentException for a particular format conversion

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a date returned from a javascript library in the format **23/10/2019 12:03:46**
and while saving in the database i am trying to convert into a carbon object like below:-

```
 $order->delivery_date =  Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/Y H:i:s',$request->time);
```

getting error

> InvalidArgumentException: Unexpected data found.

also tried these similar links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460292/carbon-carbonnow-throws-invalidargumentexception-with-message-trailing-data) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086913/invalidargumentexception-in-carboncreatefromdate-age) but not able to get out of this problem.

Comment: Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s',$request->time);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the format string seems to be wrong. Try it like this:

`$order->delivery_date =  Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s',$request->time);`